# Calling a Python script from PHP, on a MAC with XAMPP

Tags: python, php, macos, rest, mysql-connector

I want to build a RESTful API. 
I am working on a MAC, and I installed the XAMPP server.
I have a Python script that I want to call it from PHP.

My PHP file looks like:

```
$output = shell_exec("python $pyfilepath $post->id $post->name");
echo $output;
```

and there is no problem with that.

My python code looks like:

```
import sys
#import mysql.connector
def my_results(id,name):
    print("My args are:",id,name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_results(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

I can read and pass parameters to the python script, but if I try to activate the:

```
import mysql.connector
```

I am not getting any results from my_results definition.

I have everything build on python, and I just need to call my script. Any idea what is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: have you added the shebang in the first row ? `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't play any role since I am calling as 'python' my script.
'shell_exec("python $pyfilepath $post->id $post->name");'
Thank you

Comment: what mysql connector do you use ? slimmyorm ?

Comment: if you do not have it install it : `pip3 install mysql-connector-python` or `pip3 install mysql-connector`

Comment: No, I have installed it. My script works fine on Jupiter. I am rewriting it as a python file, and I want to call it from PHP. I was not able to find the error, and I decided to do one thing at the time. I have the same error even if I try to import pandas. Can you call a python script from PHP with a DB connection? 
Thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: there should be some error in your php logs. please take a look in the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I changed the:

```
$output = shell_exec("python $pyfilepath $post->id $post->name");
```

to:

```
$output = shell_exec("/anaconda3/bin/python3 $pyfilepath $post->id $post->name");
```

and it worked.
Thanks for helping Max Muster

Answer (score 0):

please try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env  php

ob_start();
passthru("python $pyfilepath $post->id $post->name");
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

or try this

```
$output = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("python $pyfilepath $post->id $post->name"));
echo $output;
```

try a simple  script  test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env  php
print("hello")
```

and call it like this

```
$output = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("test.py"));
echo $output;
```

Comment: The first one has the same behavior, while the second one does not return anything

Comment: make a simple python script like hello world an place it in your folder and try to call it with one of this methods

Comment: Yes, I can call the hello world without the 'import mysql.connector' and works fine.
I just checked the logs as you suggested, and there is an error: ImportError: No module named mysql.connector. I guess because I use anaconda is somehow installed in that specific environment. I need to fix that, and I'll post an update soon. Thanks a lot!!! At least I have a clue now on what to search.

Comment: if you do not have it install it : `pip3 install mysql-connector-python` or `pip3 install mysql-connector` if you do not have pip3 install it first `sudo easy_install pip3`